# Two particular combinations of Gauss hypergeometric functions

Tags: reference-request, hypergeometric-functions

Browsing this site and the web I could not find a reference on the following combinations of Gauss hypergeometric functions $F={}_2F_1$, for which I have reason to believe that they can be simplified or even expressed in terms of elementary functions:

For $x>0$ and $z\in \mathbb C$
$$
xF(2,z,z+1;-x)+x^{-1}F(2,z,z+1;-x^{-1})\quad=\quad ?
$$
$$
F(1,z,z+1;x)+F(1,z,z+1;x^{-1})\quad=\quad ?
$$
Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: "I have reason to believe that they can be simplified" ... What is the reason?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: They come up in the calculation of the resolvent kernel of the d'Alembertian on 3-dimensional anti-de Sitter space. In the physics literature there are some formulas to which I can compare my calculations and these formulas do not involve hypergeometric functions. I hope that by simplifying the above expressions I get something that I can compare.

Comment: Mathematica cannot do anything with these expressions. So, any simplification of them seems unlikely.